# validación de rangos con jquery a través de la base de datos

Tags: javascript, jquery, validación

Tengo tres campos en una base de datos,

la tabla se llama

> mail_messages

los datos que incluye son

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('mail_messages', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('type');
        $table->text('description');
        $table->unsignedInteger('from_value')->default('0');
        $table->unsignedInteger('to_value')->default('0');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });
}
```

Al hacer la entrada de un nuevo dato, necesito validar entre mensajes(descripciones) del mismo type(1,2,3, etc) que los rangos de from_value y to_value no sean interceptados entre otros mensajes del mismo type antiguos (guardados en la base de datos)

Si no me explico muy bien, dejo una imagen explicativa [image: explicacion]

Tengo una datatable con mensajes que uno coloca, adjunto captura
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De esa tabla, cuando yo quiero crear un nuevo "mensaje", necesito hacer la verificación para que ninguna entrada nueva intercepte su rango, es decir, que dentro de la variable type (esos COM01 en realidad son un 1 entero en la base de datos) **ningún valor de cualquier variable antigua "to_value" pueda ser MENOR que la nueva "from_value"** que quiero insertar (como la gráfica de arriba) ya que eso generaría un cruce entre rangos.

Necesito la verificación para evitar que los datos de valor se crucen con los antiguos mientras estoy creando un nuevo formulario

¿Cómo podría hacerlo a través del complemento jquery validate? Necesito acceder a la base de datos para verificar

muchas gracias por leer hasta aquí :)

este es mi formulario

```
<form id="MailMessage-form" method="POST" action="{{route('mail-message.store')}}">
                            @csrf
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="type"
                                       class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">{{__('messages.create.type')}}</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <select name="type" id="type" class="form-control">
                                        @foreach ($MailMessageTypes as $value =>$label)
                                            <option value="{{$value}}">{{$label}}</option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="description"
                                       class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">{{__('messages.create.description')}}</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <textarea class="ckeditor form-control" name="description" id="description"
                                              rows="10"> </textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="from_value"
                                       class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">{{__('messages.create.from_value')}}</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <input id="from_value" type="number" min="0"
                                           class="form-control @error('from_value') is-invalid @enderror"
                                           name="from_value"
                                           value="{{ old('from_value') }}" required autocomplete="from_value"
                                           autofocus>
                                    @error('from_value')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="to_value"
                                       class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">{{__('messages.create.to_value')}}</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <input id="to_value" type="number" min="1"
                                           class="form-control @error('to_value') is-invalid @enderror"
                                           name="to_value"
                                           value="{{ old('to_value') }}" required autocomplete="to_value" autofocus>
                                    @error('to_value')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-2">
                                    <a href="{{route('mail-message.index')}}"
                                       class="btn btn-white btn-sm">{{__('messages.create.cancel')}}</a>
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"
                                            type="submit">{{__('messages.create.save')}}</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

tengo un controlador dedicado a los requests que de momento tiene solamente estas verificaciones

```
    public function rules()
{
    return [
        'Type' => ['required|integer|max:9'],
        'Description' => ['required|text'],
        'From_Value' => ['required|integer|min:0'],
        'To_Value' => ['required|integer|min:1']
    ];
}
```

Comment: Tu pregunta es amplia y basada en opiniones y eso generará su cierre

Comment: @BetaM lo siento, pensé que me estaba expresando bien, ya actualicé la pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Importante:**

Esta validación necesita acceder a la base de datos, por ende, no es bueno que lo manejes con jquery validate, te sugiero que uses ese plugin para validaciones simples de lado del cliente, pero para personalizadas que accedan a la base de datos manéjala desde el validador del controlador y captura los mensajes de error desde blade.

**Solución:**

Necesitas hacer una validación personalizada, existen muchas maneras de hacerlas, aquí te presento una, que es crearla dentro del método `boot()` en tu archivo `AppServiceProvider.php`.

```
Validator::extend('rangos_no_repetidos_del_mismo_tipo',
    function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
        $data = $validator->getData();
        
        $existenRegistros = Mensaje::where('type', $data['type'])
            ->where(function ($query) use ($data) {
               $query->where('from_value ', '<=', $data['from_value'])
                     ->where('to_value', '>=', $data['from_value']);
           })->orWhere(function ($query) use ($data) {
              $query->where('from_value', '<=', $data['to_value']);
              $query->where('to_value', '>=', $data['to_value']);
          })->count();

        return $existenRegistros == 0;
});
```

Básicamente, debes buscar si existen registros que incluyan el nuevo registro que quieres ingresar, si existe alguno, entonces la validación hará su trabajo.
Asumí que tienes un `request` en tu `controlador` con los mismos nombres de tu modelo.

```
$request->validate([
    'type' => 'required',
    'from_value' => 'required|rangos_no_repetidos_del_mismo_tipo',
    'to_value' => 'required|gt:from_value|rangos_no_repetidos_del_mismo_tipo',
]);
```

El query que construí es simple, sólo debes buscar registros del mismo tipo que estén dentro de ciertos rangos.

**Mensaje de validación**

Existen distintas maneras de agregar un mensaje de validación aquí, lo añades directamente en el request, en la instancia Validator dentro de boot() o también puedes agregarla a tu archivos de lenguajes.

1er opción:

```
$request->validate([
      'type' => 'required',
      'from_value' => 'required|rangos_no_repetidos_del_mismo_tipo',
      'to_value' => 'required|gt:from_value|rangos_no_repetidos_del_mismo_tipo',
 ],[
   'from_value.rangos_no_repetidos_del_mismo_tipo' => "El rango ingresado se encuentra en uso"
  ]);
```

2da opción: Dicho método puede recibir un nuevo parámetro que será el mensaje de validación.

```
Validator::extend('rangos_no_repetidos_del_mismo_tipo',
    ...
}, "El rango ingresado se encuentra en uso");
```

3ra opción: En tus archivo de lenguaje (es/en) `resources/lang/xx/validation.php` añades lo siguiente, dependiendo del idioma:

```
'custom' => [
    'from_value' => [
        'rangos_no_repetidos_del_mismo_tipo' => 'El rango ingresado se encuentra en uso',
    ],
],
```

Comment: @L. Flor, hola, hice lo que pusiste en la respuesta, sin embargo no sé dónde pueda estar el error, introduce los datos en la tabla como si nada, voy a actualizar mi pregunta incluyendo los request que tengo y el nombre de la DB

Comment: Cambiaste los nombres del modelo y de las variables para que se adapten a tu proyecto y además agregaste la nueva validación así como te la planteé?

Comment: así es, cambié las variables, los nombres del modelo y agregué las validaciones al request que ya tenía, también incluí validator en el serviceprovider

Comment: Las otras validaciones que tienes en tu `rules()`, funcionan? Sólo la que te puse no funciona?

Comment: hay algo raro, cuando hago el debug solo ingresa a la primera línea, la que verifica si Type es un entero, voy a seguir averiguando qué pasa

Comment: Si pones tus reglas entre [ ] deben ir separados por comas, para que uses el separador | es mejor que quites esos brackets [ ]

Comment: muchísimas gracias @L. Flor!!

te pago una cerveza por tu tiempo, jaja

Comment: tengo una ultima pregunta, en el view obtengo el mensaje de rangos_no_repetidos_del_mismo_tipo cuando se activa, estoy usando archivos de traducción en resources->lang pero no sé cómo poner ese ahí

Comment: Añadiré ese caso a la respuesta

Comment: muchas gracias por tu tiempo @L. Flor, finalmente lo hice desde el archivo de idiomas, ya que la tengo en dos idiomas, gracias